# I updated my apps and now I can't get into Ubuntu

Tags: boot, apt, grub2, gnome, upgrade

I wanted to update my Gnome3 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS so I downloaded the PPAs and ran:

`sudo apt update` and `sudo apt dist-upgrade`

It took me a while to update, and it made me choose between gdm3 and lightdm. I chose the former, and Gnome is updated to 3.22.

Later during the day, I try to used GNOME Tweak Tools to play around with, update, remove old extensions, etc. Some extensions were bugging out and refreshing wasn't working so I decided to restart my laptop (I dual boot Windows). What it gave me was a screen showing `/dev/sda1: clean, ##/#### file, ##/#### blocks`. I restarted again, and the Grub menu showed just fine. Whenever I choose to boot into Ubuntu, it **either shows me a blank black screen or the purple splash page with just the logo**. I can't do anything while I'm here, and it never gets me to the login.

Any idea how to fix all this? I'm fairly new to Ubuntu so I don't want to do anything I shouldn't be doing. I searched on Google that Nvidia has do with the blank screen, but I don't have a GPU; my laptop is running integrated graphics. `Ctrl+Alt+F1` doesn't seem to work in that screen either.

Comment: Hold `Ctrl-Alt-F1` simultaneously, and wait. Login and try `sudo service lightdm restart`. Or try `sudo service lightdm stop;sudo service gdm3 start`. One of those might get you a graphics environment whit which to begin your investigation of this problem.

Comment: Held `Ctrl-Alt-F1` for 30 secs, and it didn't do anything. It stayed on the purple splash page.

Comment: "I'm fairly new to Ubuntu" and doing such risky upgrades do not compute. Perhaps better boot a live session, backup and reinstall . It may well be faster than troubleshooting.

Comment: These are count as risky upgrades? So I can boot a USB drive with the Ubuntu install to back up before I reinstall?

Comment: Yes, obviously, even mentioned in the PPAs pages, and yes, you can use a live session to access your files.